# How to rearrange rows based on one group in Libreoffice spreadsheet?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-calc

I would like to rearrange the LibreOffice Calc rows, based on the values in the first column. For the sheet given below;

`| Object Name |  Value 1  |  Value 2  |  Value 3  |...|  Value N  | OUTPUT  |
 |      ABC    |     1     |     0     |     0     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |
 |      BCZ    |     0     |     1     |     0     |...|     1     |    XYZ  |
 |      FEG    |     1     |     0     |     1     |...|     1     |    YZX  |
 |      ABC    |     1     |     1     |     0     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |
 |      ABC    |     0     |     0     |     1     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |
 |      BCZ    |     1     |     0     |     0     |...|     1     |    XYZ  |
 |      FEG    |     1     |     1     |     0     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |`

I want to rearrange the rows is as in following sheet:

`| Object Name |  Value 1  |  Value 2  |  Value 3  |...|  Value N  | OUTPUT  |
 |      ABC    |     1     |     0     |     0     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |
 |      ABC    |     1     |     1     |     0     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |
 |      ABC    |     0     |     0     |     1     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |
 |      BCZ    |     0     |     1     |     0     |...|     1     |    XYZ  |
 |      BCZ    |     1     |     0     |     0     |...|     1     |    XYZ  |
 |      FEG    |     1     |     0     |     1     |...|     1     |    YZX  |
 |      FEG    |     1     |     1     |     0     |...|     0     |    XYZ  |`

How can I get this in LibreOffice Calc? Help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "OUTPUT" is in column G:

1. Select columns A through G and go to `Data -> Sort`.
2. For `Sort Key 1`, choose "Object Name" from the list.
3. Press OK.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm!